# How can I correct a Terraform, Error: Incorrect attribute value type error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here is a the snippets of relevant code:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state     = "available"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count                   = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.${20+count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "prod" {
  name                      = "prod-web"
  count                     = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)
....
  vpc_zone_identifier       = aws_subnet.private_subnet[count.index]
```

Above, on the vpc_zone_identifier line, it returns

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type, four times, aws_subnet.private_subnet is tuple with 4 elements
│     │ count.index is 0
```

indexed 0, 1, 2, and 3. If 4 subnets are the result, what is wrong with that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I see here that you are creating one autoscaling group for each subnet, which sounds a little strange.

Comment: Is that what it looks like? I am simply trying to spin up ec2 instances, 2-5 based on demand, distributed to three subnets, and each subnet in a separate Availability Zone in the region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to obtain `id` of the subnet:

```
vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.private_subnet[count.index].id'
```

or without `count`:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "prod" {
  name                      = "prod-web"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = aws_subnet.private_subnet[*].id
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Marcin, still receive same error.

Comment: vpc_zone_identifier expects a list of ids, this is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute for `aws_autoscaling_group`, the `vpc_zone_identifier`, accepts a list of subnet ids, while you are passing a full resource, hence the error type you are getting.

Also, you are creating multiple autoscaling groups with that `count`, you should remove it.

This would look something like this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "prod" {
  name                      = "prod-web"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = aws_subnet.private_subnet[*].id
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [terraform doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group) suggests, the `vpc_zone_identifier` expects a list, but you are passing tuple.
You can use something like this -

```
vpc_zone_identifier = [x, y, z]
```